# Prevent more than 1 write a second to a Firestore document when using a counter with cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

## Background:

I have a Firestore database with a *users* collection.  Each user is a document which contains a *contacts* collection.  Each document in that collection is a single *contact*.

Since firestore does not have a "count" feature for all documents, and since I don't want to read *all* contacts to count how many contacts a user has, I trigger cloud functions when a contact is added or deleted which increments or decrements *numberOfContacts* in the user document. In order to make the function idempotent, it has to do multiple reads and writes to prevent incrementing the counter more than once if it's called more than once for the same document. This means that I need to have a different collection of eventIDs that I've already handled so I don't duplicate it. This requires me to run another function once a month to go through each user deleting all such documents (which is a lot of reads and some writes).

---

## Issue

Now the challenge is that the user can import his/her contacts. So if a user imports 10,000 contacts, this function will get fired 10,000 times in quick succession.

How do I prevent that?

---

## Current approach:

Right now I am adding a field in the contact document that indicates that the addition was part of an import. This gets the cloud function to not increment.

I perform the operation from the client 499 contacts at a time in a transaction, which also increments the count as the 500th write.  That way the count stays consistent if something failed halfway.

Is this really the best way?  It seems so complicated to just have a count of contacts available. I end up doing multiple reads and writes each time a single contact changes plus I have to run a cleanup function every month.

I keep thinking there's gotta be a simpler way.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: Thanks, Doug. I actually don't want to do distributed shards because my normal use-case doesn't have a lot of writes.  It's only when contacts are imported, so I want to keep the normal use-case simple and reads faster.  

I have a solution that works, it just annoys me because overall a simple issue of "how many contacts does user X have" is just ridiculously complex.

Comment: It's not possible to disable a function temporarily for certain invocations.  The data to work with has to be in the document that changed.  Idempotence also necessarily increases the amount of work a function has to perform.  I don't think there is an easy way out.

Answer (score 0):

For those who're curious, it seems like the approach I am taking is the best appraoch.

I add a field in the contact document that indicates that the addition was part of an import (bulkAdd = true). This gets the cloud function to not increment.

I have another cloud function add the contacts 200 at a time (I do FieldValue.timestamp and that counts as another write, so it's 400 writes).  I do this in a batch and the 401th write in the batch is the increment count.  That way I can bulk import contacts without having to bombard a single document with writes.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem with increments**

There are duplicate-safe operations like `FieldValue.arrayUnion()` & `FieldValue.arrayRemove()`. I wrote a bit about that approach here: [Firebase function document.create and user.create triggers firing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828406/firebase-function-document-create-and-user-create-triggers-firing-multiple-times/57829348#57829348)

By this approach you make your user document contain a special array field with contact IDs. Once the contact is added to a subcollection and your function is triggered, the contact's id can be written to this field. If the function is triggered twice or more times for one contact, there will be only one instance of it written into the master user doc. But the actual size can be fetched on the client or with one more function triggered on the user doc update. This is a bit simplier than having eventIDs.

**Problem with importing 10k+ contacts**

This is a bit philosophically.
If I got it, the problem is that a user performs 10k writes. Than these 10k writes trigger 10k functions, which perform additional 10k writes to the master doc (and same amount of reads if they use eventIDs document)?

You can make a special subcollection just for importing multiple contacts to your DB. Instead of writing 10k docs to the DB, the client would create one but big document with 10k contact fields, which triggers a cloud function. The mentioned function would read it all, make the neccessary 10k contact writes + 1 write to master doc with all the arrayUnions. You would just need to think how to prevent 10k invoked function writes (adding a special metadata field like yours bulkAdd)

*This is just an opinion.*