# Firebase function document.create and user.create triggers firing multiple times

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to keep track of the number of documents in collections and the number of users in my Firebase project. I set up some .create triggers to update a stats document using increment, but sometimes the .create functions trigger multiple times for a single creation event. This happens with both Firestore documents and new users. Any ideas?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore')
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore()

/* for counting documents created */
exports.countDoc = functions.firestore
  .document('collection/{docId}')
  .onCreate((change, context) => {
    const docId = context.params.docId
    db.doc('stats/doc').update({
      'docsCreated': firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
    })
    return true;
  });

/* for counting users created */
exports.countUsers = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  db.doc('stats/doc').update({
    'usersCreated': firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
  })
  return true;
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some advice on how to achieve your functions' *idempotency*.

There are `FieldValue.arrayUnion()` & `FieldValue.arrayRemove()` functions which safely remove and add elements to an array, without duplicates or errors if the element being deleted is nonexistent.

You can make array fields in your documents called 'users' and 'docs' and add there data with `FieldValue.arrayUnion()` by triggered functions. With that approach you can retrieve the actual sizes on the client side by getting `users` & `docs` fields and calling `.size()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should expect that a background trigger could possibly be executed multiple times per event.  This should be very rare, but not impossible.  It's part of the guarantee that Cloud Functions gives you for "at-least-once execution".  Since the internal infrastructure is entirely asynchronous with respect to the execution of your code on a dedicated server instance, that infrastructure might not receive the signal that your function finished successfully.  In that case, it triggers the function again in order to ensure delivery.

It's recommended that you write your function to be idempotent in order to handle this situation, if it's important for your app.  This is not always a very simple thing to implement correctly, and could also add a lot of weight to your code.  There are also many ways to do this for different sorts of scenarios.  But the choice is yours.

Read more about it in the [documentation for execution guarantees](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees).